# Illegal string offset 'slug' PDO

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I'm trying to pull the pages from my database and make them an actual page url:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypqbB.png

```
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM pages");
$stmt->execute();
$menu = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($menu as $page) {
    if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $page['slug']){
        require_once('inc/page/' . $page['slug'] . '.php');
    }
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. I keep getting this

> Illegal string offset 'slug'

error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: you should normalize your db. comma-separated values are hard to work with

Comment: Any suggestions how to do it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$page` is actually a string, hence the error.  `fetch` returns one row, so this:

```
$menu = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($menu as $page) { ...
```

actually loops through each column as a string.

Instead:

```
$stmt->execute();

while ($page = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$menu = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to `$menu = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
or
remove the `foreach` and use `$menu['slug']` instead of `$page['slug']`.

Answer (score -2):

You should never select all rows when you need only one.

```
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT slug FROM pages WHERE slug = ?");
$stmt->execute([basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])]);
$slug = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if($slug) {
    require_once "inc/page/$slug.php";
}
```